# building multiple polygons by function in google maps javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I want to build a lot of areas in google maps, and have each defined with a polygon.
If I do it one by one it works without a problem (inside the initialize func):

```
name = new google.maps.Polygon({
           paths: coords,
           strokeColor: 'darkgreen',
           strokeOpacity: 0.3,
           strokeWeight: 1,
           fillOpacity: 0.05
       });

//some event
//highlights polygon when mouseover
google.maps.event.addListener(name, 'mouseover', function () {
name.setOptions({ fillColor: 'yellow', fillOpacity: 0.25 });
});

//then displaying it on the map:
name.setMap(map);
```

Now I want to have a function to just put in the coords to build the polygons, something like this. But just calling the function stops other polygons from being rendered, so I know there is a problem calling it:

```
iName = new drawPolygon(polyName, coords);
iName.setMap(map);
```

The function looks like this:

```
function drawPolygon(polyName, coords) {
       polyName =  new google.maps.Polygon({
           paths: coords,
           strokeColor: 'darkgreen',
           strokeOpacity: 0.3,
           strokeWeight: 1,
           //fillColor: 'green',
           fillOpacity: 0.05
       });


       //highlights polygon when mouseover
       google.maps.event.addListener(polyName, 'mouseover', function () {
           polyName.setOptions({ fillColor: 'yellow', fillOpacity: 0.25 });
       });
   }
```

any help as to why, how am I calling it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

drawPolygon doesn't have a return statement. It returns `null`.  `null`doesn't have a .setMap method.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on geocodezip's answer, just add a return statement to your function.

```
function drawPolygon(polyName, coords) {
       polyName =  new google.maps.Polygon({
           paths: coords,
           strokeColor: 'darkgreen',
           strokeOpacity: 0.3,
           strokeWeight: 1,
           fillOpacity: 0.05
       });


       //highlights polygon when mouseover
       google.maps.event.addListener(polyName, 'mouseover', function () {
           polyName.setOptions({ fillColor: 'yellow', fillOpacity: 0.25 });
       });

       return polyName;
}
```

I'd also be inclined to in that case not bother passing `polyName` into the function as an argument.  You don't bother showing us the code where you create the polyName variable prior to calling drawPolygon.  But I assume you're not doing anything particularly clever with it that would require you to do so.

So refactored:

```
iName = new drawPolygon(coords);
iName.setMap(map);

function drawPolygon(coords) {
       var polyName =  new google.maps.Polygon({
           paths: coords,
           strokeColor: 'darkgreen',
           strokeOpacity: 0.3,
           strokeWeight: 1,
           fillOpacity: 0.05
       });


       //highlights polygon when mouseover
       google.maps.event.addListener(polyName, 'mouseover', function () {
           polyName.setOptions({ fillColor: 'yellow', fillOpacity: 0.25 });
       });

       return polyName;
}
```

Comment: thanks, was almost there by now...a few minor tweeks. I did forget to return something :0